# Close current toggle div when clicked onto another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So right now, I have a basic slide and toggle script which with help now has a background added to it when clicked. However, I would like it so when another "CLICK ME" is clicked it closes that div and opens the new div. In essence I don't want toggled divs constantly overlapping each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/schermerb/rAMQT/6/

```
<div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>
<div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>
<div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>
<div class="toggleBtn">CLICK ME</div>
<div class="below">OH NO IM HIDDEN</div>

.toggleBtn {
    font:14px noral Futura, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    margin:50px;
    cursor:pointer
}
.below {
    background:red;
}
.toggleBtn.active{
    background:blue;   
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var content = $('.below').hide();
        $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
            $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();

            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
        //register the handler to button element inside .below
        $('.below .close').on('click', function () {
            //find the ancestor .below element of the clicked button
            $(this).closest('.below').slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.next('.below').slideToggle().siblings('.below').slideUp();
       $this.toggleClass('active').siblings('.toggleBtn.active').removeClass('active');
```

instead of

```
     $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tbyyz/)**

Comment: Is there a way to close the background of "CLICK ME" too as well? If so, that will be perfect.

Comment: @Blake oh yeah sure.. WIll udpate

Comment: @Blake If you want the others to slide up and then slideToggle this one you can use the callback of slide.. Not sure if you are looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var the_others = $('.active').not(this);
the_others.removeClass('active');
the_others.next('.below').slideUp();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7wPR/)